# Un Subscribing From Azure Notification Hub Tags in Android

Tags: android, azure, google-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I am registering a user when he Signup and , subscribing to a tag , where using his mobile number as tag. Now , even if I am using another user id on same device , its also gives previous tags notification , because GCM id for the device is same. I don't want to unregister from GCM each time a user logging out or a different user sign in. How can I unsubscribe from all previous tags while a new user sign in or existing user sign out.

Brief: How to unsubscribe from all tags of Azure Notification Hubs.

Answer (score 0):

From the logic you've described, once the device token is retrieved from GCM, you register user with Notification Hubs using subscribed tag and phone number as separate tags. When a new user signs in, the GCM id will still be the same since GCM identifies devices to push to, not users. You need to unregister with Notification Hubs using 1. [delete registration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223268.aspx) for old user and recreate registration for new user, or 2. [update registration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223262.aspx) with new user information. There are also equivalent APIs for installation model if that is what you are using. And these APIs are available in our various SDKs as well (e.g. [.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.aspx)). Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there any way to check , particular device is already registered in azure notification hub or not ? For calling the delete api , you have mentioned, need registration id. So , is there any way to get registration id if that device is already registered

Comment: We recommend for registration ids to be stored on devices to avoid duplicated registrations. There's no source of truth to check if a device is already registered because device tokens are not permanent.